# Not getting json data into mapview, getting blank map only

Tags: android, android-mapview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

i am fetching JSON data into MapView to show locations, but whenever i run my program not getting data into Map just getting blank map without json data, here i am placing my json data and Activity Code, please tell me where i am doing mistake
    {
    "maps": [
    {

```
"title": "Place One",
"latitude" : "46.483742",
"longitude" : "7.663157",
"country": "Switzerland"
},
{
"title" : "Place Two",
"latitude" : "59.25235",
"longitude" : "18.465536",
"country" : "Sweden"
},
{
"title" : "Place Three",
"latitude" : "56.404182",
"longitude" : "-3.818855",
"country" : "Scotland"
}
]
}
```

Activity Code:-

```
public class Main extends MapActivity {
public GeoPoint point;
TapControlledMapView mapView; // use the custom TapControlledMapView
List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
Drawable drawable;
SimpleItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay;

@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mapView = (TapControlledMapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.setSatellite(false);
    // dismiss balloon upon single tap of MapView (iOS behavior) 
    mapView.setOnSingleTapListener(new OnSingleTapListener() {      
        public boolean onSingleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            itemizedOverlay.hideAllBalloons();
            return true;

        }
    });

    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();        
    drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    itemizedOverlay = new SimpleItemizedOverlay
            (drawable, mapView);        
    itemizedOverlay.setShowClose(false);
    itemizedOverlay.setShowDisclosure(true);
    itemizedOverlay.setSnapToCenter(false);

     class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    // Perform a GET request for a JSON list
    HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet
            ("https://dl.!!!!.com/maps.json");
    // Get the response that sends back
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = client.execute(request);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Convert this response into a readable string
    String jsonString = null;
    try {
        jsonString = StreamUtils.convertToString
                (response.getEntity().getContent());
    } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Create a JSON object that we can use from the String
    JSONObject json = null;
    try {
        json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }


               try{

     JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("maps");
     Log.e("log_tag", "Opening JSON Array ");
        for(int i=0;i < jsonArray.length();i++)
            {                       

            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String latitude =  jsonObject.getString("latitude");
                String longitude =  jsonObject.getString("longitude");
                String title =  jsonObject.getString("title");
                String country = jsonObject.getString("country");


                double lat = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(longitude);


                     Log.e("log_tag", "ADDING GEOPOINT"+title); 

                      point = new GeoPoint(
                             (int) (lat * 1E6), 
                             (int) (lng * 1E6));
                    OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point, title, 
                            country);
                    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);

                    }
               }catch(JSONException e)        {
                 Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
            } 

               itemizedOverlay.populateNow(); 

               mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
                    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            MapController controller = mapView.getController();
                        controller.setCenter(point);
                        controller.setZoom(7);

                    } else {

              // example restoring focused state of overlays
                        int focused;
                focused = savedInstanceState.getInt("focused_1", -1);
            if (focused >= 0) {
                              itemizedOverlay.setFocus
                       (itemizedOverlay.getItem(focused));
                        }
                    }
                    return jsonString;   }
     }

     }
```

Comment: could you please tell me where i am missing

Comment: @Stanley Don't write network related task in main UI Thread, use separate thread for network related task.

Comment: Hi Dipak, thanks for reply but i am confuse where and how i need to write my code, could you please write it for me, please use above code, it would be easy to understand for me, further i will use same way...

Comment: what code i need to move in onPostExecute()method, i have tried several but getting errors, could you help me out

Answer (score 1):

The exception says all: you are trying to do a network operation by loading the maps inside the UI thread. This is a bad idea, as network access is slow and will block the UI while it is running.

You should move the maps loading into a different thread e.g. by using an `AsyncTask`.
Basically you define a class that extends `AsyncTask` and then runs the download in `doInBackground()` and fills the result into the view within `onPostExecute()`.
See the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for more information.

In your case you need to put this code block into the `doInBackground()` method:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
// Perform a GET request for a JSON list
HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet("https://dl.###.com/maps.json");
// Get the response that sends back
HttpResponse response = null;
try {
    response = client.execute(request);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

// Create a JSON object that we can use from the String
JSONObject json = null;
try {
    json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
} catch (JSONException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

and make sure that it returns the `json` object for further processing (basically the lines that follow that code) within `onPostExecute()`

Have a look at the docs for an example. You can also look at [this code](https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/master/src/de/bsd/zwitscher/OneTweetActivity.java#L891) for more examples.

Comment: Heiko, could you please write your idea, by insert my code, where you think it should be, because i don't know what and where to place and write....

Comment: Thanks, i have tried but i still facing problem, could you please write it for me, like you said then i will match my code and able to find the reason or my mistake

Comment: Hi Heiko, i have tried your idea, now i am getting Map but without JSON Data, and i did not write any code within postexecute() method, because i am not getting what to write under this one, could you tell me like earlier you helped

Comment: Stanley, you need to pass the json object out of `doInBackground` and work on it in the `onPostExecute` method and then populating your map display from within the `onPostExecute` method.

Comment: ok thnx i will try .....